# Install dependent app in multi-app project

Tags: android-studio, gradle

In my Android project I have two apps, which I will refer to as AppA and AppB. I need AppB installed in order for AppA to work properly. In Android Studio, if I run the debug configuration for AppA, only AppA is installed. How can I get gradle to also install AppB when it installs AppA?

Answer (score 0):

Include in the gradle settings file "path/AppA/settings.gradle" this two lines :

include 'AppB'

project(':AppB').projectDir = file('path/AppB')